# What does "res" stand for?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, closures, google-signin

I notice in swift, we often use some variation of the following code:

```
func signInWithEmail(email: String, password: String){
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password){ (res, err) in
        ...

    }
```

What does "res" stand for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"res" is standing for "Response".

It's related for the used Library. generally, Your posted code is originally written as follows:

```
 signIn(withEmail: String, password: String, completion: @nonescaping (Response, Error) -> Void) {

  ...

  if !error {

    completion(res, nil) 

  } else {

    completion(nil, err)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case "res" means authResults, like user uid, email, etc